# I have problems that ASP.NET DropdownList, SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to display Category SelectList.

Item table is

```
    <Table("Item")>
    Public Class Item
        <Key>
        Public Property ITM_Idx As Integer
        <Required>
        Public Property CAR_Idx As Integer
```

and then, Category table is

```
<Key>
Property CAG_Idx As Integer
<Column>
<Required, StringLength(50)>
Property CAG_Name As String
<Column>
<Required>
Property CAG_CD As String
```

so, I want to create selectlist when User creates item

but I don't make dropdownlist..

please.. help me

googling, stackoverflow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you say `DropdownList` - are you referring to WebForms (as in `.aspx` and `<asp:DropDownList runat="server">`?